# Downsides of using Makefile rules for deployment?

Tags: deployment, makefile

I have an open-source project where I'm using Make for things like tests and static checks. The deployment process is approximately this:

```
make html
rsync static_pages my_domain.com:static_pages
ssh my_domain.com "cp -r static_pages /var/www/webroot"
```

Is there a reason not to have this deployment process publicly in the Makefile? Does Make have gotchas that make it unsuitable for deployment? Is there a security issue revealing server names or directory structure? Or something else that I haven't though of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as this does the job, it is OK. You worry about privacy of some rules, but why is your make script more vulnerable to alien curiosity than any other process on your build or deployment  workstation? If this is because make script is published as open source, the easy workaround could be to keep sensitive names as environment variables, e.g.

```
html:
    rsync static_pages $(DOMAIN):static_pages
    ssh $(DOMAIN) "cp -r static_pages $(WEBROOT)"
```

Comment: The concern would be publishing the build script as part of the open-source tools instead of keeping it separate. The alternative would be to package the makefile with rules for testing and building but keep the deployment script separate.